# Function in scheme to find median

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to Scheme and I am using Dr.Racket to try to find the median of the list.

If the length of list L is odd, the function median returns the median element in the list. If the length of L is even, the function median returns 0. example

```
(median ‘(1)) returns 1
(median ‘(1 2)) returns 0
(median ‘(1 2 3)) returns 2
(median ‘( 1 2 3 4) returns 0
```

I am only allowed to use:

- null?
- car
- cdr
- else
- =
- +
- median
- cond
- if
- user defined names (for my variables)
- integer literals
- parentheses

We are not allowed to use two functions. It should be something like `(define median (lambda (<list L followed by parameters of your choice initially set to zero>) (cond )))` and it should have only one recursive function. All auxiliary parameters must be numeric (not lists) and should have initial values set to zero. For example, if L is `‘(1 2 3 4)` and decide to use one additional auxiliary parameters, median should be called `(median '(1 2 3 4) 0 )`.

The median divides the list into two sets with equal length. This is the defining property of the median: if the number of the elements preceding the median equals the number of the elements succeeding it, then the element is the median. Therefore, in order to find the median, for each list element, one needs to count the number of elements that precede the given element and the number of the elements that succeed it. If these two numbers are the same, the median is found. The problem representation involves the following variables: - the list L; - a target element (potential median), say “target”; - a counter for the number of the elements preceding the target, say count1 - a counter for the number of the elements succeeding the target, say count2 I came up with something like this:

```
(define median(lambda (list target count1 count2 loop )
  (cond
  ((null? list)(if (= count1 count2) target 0))
  ((if (= loop 1)
  (if (= target (median (cdr list) target count1 (+ 1 count2) 1 ))
  target
  (median (cdr list) (car list) (+ count1 1) 0 1 )
  ))))))
```

But I am stuck here...can anyone help?

Comment: We are only supposed to give a input with a list and rest of the auxiliary parameters as 0.  if L is ‘(1 2 3 4) and decide to use 3 additional auxiliary parameters, median should be called (median '(1 2 3 4) 0 0 0). auxiliary parameters  should have initial values set to zero. The tortoise and hare algorithm does not solve this condition. And hence i asked a new question. Sorry if i was not clear in my question before. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I am stuck here"? In which way does that not work? What results are you getting, and how do they differ from the intended results?

Comment: Is there a way to find a median wihtout using tortoise and hare algorithm like how i explained with the help of counters and not using any built in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your constraints well this should do:

```
(define median
  (lambda (lst pass cnt1 cnt2)
    (cond
      ; pass 0 = initial call - call pass 1 then pass 2
      ((= pass 0) (median lst 2 (median lst 1 0 0) 0))
      ; pass 1 = determine the position of the median (-1 or n//2)
      ((= pass 1) (if (null? lst)
                      (if (= cnt1 cnt2) -1 (sub1 cnt1))
                      (median (cdr lst) 1 (add1 cnt2) cnt1)))
      ; pass 2 = find element
      (else       (cond
                    ((eqv? cnt1 -1) 0)
                    ((eqv? cnt1 0) (car lst))
                    (else (median (cdr lst) 2 (sub1 cnt1) 0)))))))
```

It basically has 3 passes, and some parameters have different meaning for different passes, so of course you'd never write such a thing in real world.

Testing:

```
> (median '(1) 0 0 0)
1
> (median '(1 2) 0 0 0)
0
> (median '(1 2 3) 0 0 0)
2
> (median '(1 2 3 4) 0 0 0)
0
> (median '(1 2 3 4 5) 0 0 0)
3
```